# How can I use author-year citation style in LyX?

Tags: bibtex, lyx, natbib, jabref, authoryear

I use the LyX editor in Windows 10.

I started with an article that already included bibliography created in the document itself. I do not know how it was created.

I created a database in JabRef with the same.

In Document > Settings > Bibliography, I chose

- Style format: `Natlib (BibTeX)`
- Variant: `Author-year`
- Defaut BibTeX style: `plainnat`
- Bibliography Generation: `Default`

At the end of the document, I inserted the bibliography. In the dialog of insertion, I chose Style: `plainnat`. **Question 1:** What's the relation between the Style specified here and the Default BibTeX Style mentioned above?

In the Lyx's window, I see the references in the chosen formats: `Author(year)` or `(Author, year)` as chosen.

When I press Ctr+R to generate the pdf, I get a window containing:

- Errors:

  Package natlib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
  Package natlib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
  Package natlib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
- Description:

  ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

  Check the bibliography entries for non-compliant syntax,
  or select author-year BibTeX style, e.g. plainnat

Pressing the button `Show Output Anyway` at the bottom of the window, I get the pdf if I am very lucky. Usually, I get another error: `There was an error opening this document. This file cannot be found.` Pressing `Ok` in the error's window and again `Show Output Anyway` a random number of times, I finally get a pdf in Adobe, which is the general default pdf viewer in my PC. Before inserting the bibliography, I got my pdf's in SumatraPDF, which I have chosen for the output of LyX.

In the body of the printed article, the `year` of the cited source does not appear. Instead of a citation like `(Author, year)`, I get just a number in square brackets, like `[5]`. Instead of a citation like `Author(year)`, I get `Author[3]. The numbers in square brackets depend on the order in which references appear at the end of the document.

At the end of the document, I see tow bibliographies: the one created by my coauthor and the one created by me. References (at the end of the document) are preceded by consecutive numbers in square brackets. This is unusual in the author-year style.

**Question 2:** How can get printed citations in the `Author(year)` and `(Author, year)` formats while avoiding the error messages shown above?

**Question 3:** How can get a list of references without numbering?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When changing bibliography styles, it's prudent to first delete all auxilliary files, especially the .blg, .bbl, .log, and .bst files. Incidentally, there's a persistent typo in your query: The option's name is `natbibapa`, not NatLibapa`. Is this typo present in the lyx distribution as well?

Comment: Check  the LaTeX code that you actually obtain, It should be `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`  in the preamble, `\citet{foo}` or`\citet{foo}` for cites in text and  finally  `\bibliographystyle{plainnat} \bibliography{yourbibfilename}`. Them the  result must be some like ` Foo  [1990]` or `[Foo, 1990]` with  the default processor (bibtex), not numbers.  Otherwise  you make something wrong.  Type  `round` in "Options:"   to use parentheses instead of brackets. The code in the preamble should be now    `\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your answer. There was previous bibliography, constructed by my coauthor, with LyX's Bibliography environment at the end to the document. Now I see that mine and his where interfering. Things are working much better after deleting my coauthor's bilbiography and deleting auxiliary files after changing styles, as you suggested. Thanks again!